# How to automatically increment pom version with maven, for example 1.2.0 to 1.3.0

Tags: maven, jenkins, sh

Trying to increment automatically application version in pom.xml file (in jenkins pipeline).

I have tried with:

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform -B
```

But I get this error: "Missing required setting: scm connection or developer connection"
I don't quite get why is this needed, for the increment..
Are there any other options to increment version in pom.xml?

I would like to use maven but I'm fine with "manual" solutions as well...

edited: this needs to be done automatically, like 'mvn versions:set -DnewVersion="next minor version"'

Comment: `mvn release:prepare release:perform -B -DdevelopmentVersion=1.3.0-SNAPSHOT` because `1.3.0` is not a development version. The missing setting is more a problem because you don't have correctly configured the scm entries in the pom file to use maven-release-plugin...

Answer (score 1):

What about

`mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.3.0`

?

Comment: Ah, forgot as this is on pipeline I need to increment version automatically to next minor. Like when the dependency or parent has updated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers! I got this solved with:

> sh "mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set 
> -DnewVersion='${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0' 
> versions:commit"